# HTML5Builder language selection on multiple pages

Tags: internationalization, html5builder

Have language selection like this on page1:
 function Image12Click($sender, $params)
    {  global $application;
      $application->Language = "English (United Kingdom)";
      $this->Language = "English (United Kingdom)";
    }

Both page1 and page2 are translated, and I open page2 like this:

function Button1Click($sender, $params)
    {
      header("Location: page2.php");
    }

Page2 always open with default language and the user have to do language selection on every page. How can I preserve the selected language when navigating from page1 to page2?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by saving the selected language to a cookie, and load the cookie on subsequent pages.